# Can I setup Google Analytics to work on my local Oracle Webcenter Portal?

Tags: google-analytics, portal, webcenter, webcenter-sites

Our customer wants to use the google analystics with webcenter portal. But webcenter works on a local server. Is it possible to make the analystics work on local server? Is it possible the google analytics work with the webcenter portal?

Comment: I don't know webcenter portal but as long as it has access to the internet and can upload to http://www.google-analytics.com/collect it will work.